# Python DataFrame printing style randomly changing

Tags: python, dataframe, visual-studio-code, pyodbc

I am using python 3.7.7 and visual studio code 1.58.2. I am querying a mysql data base with pyodbc but I believe the issue I am seeing is occuring outside of this.

```
import pyodbc as po
import pandas as pd 

conn = po.connect('Dricer={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server};'
                  'Server=<server_name>;'
                  'Database=<database_name>;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,conn)
conn.close()
df.head()
```

sometimes the printed df looks this:

```
    COL1    COL2    COL3
0   123     456     678
1   901     234     567
2   890     123     456
```

sometimes it looks like this:

```
    COL1    COL2\    
0   123     456    
1   901     234     
2   890     123    

   COL3
0   678
1   567
2   456
```

and other times it even is printed in a nicer table with alternating row shading...any suggestion or places to look for answers would be helpful. There doesn't seem to be a pattern of when or why because it changes with the same calls. One time it changed when I resized my screen. Or maybe I am imagining...but I haven't found much help from the webs. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe it was caused by pandas options on formatting. Pls check `display.max_columns` and `display.max_colwidth`.

Comment: @yoonghm I appreciate the response. It was a good idea but I changed those to various different ranges with no success as far as the actual styling.

Comment: Please run `print(df.head())`, and what are the outputs for multiple runs?

Comment: @yoonghm print(df.head()) prints the same. I appreciate the help. I wouldn't consider myself a beginner but it seems something as important as correctly displaying a df should have more suggestions to fix it. I am not finding much help online.

Comment: @yoonghm it looks like it has something to do with only allowing 7 columns after the 7th excluding the index, it gets pushed to the bottom

Comment: @gordthompson  ```pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False```  did the trick. it would be nice if others with this issue could find it quicker. Isnt this exactly what this board is designed for. thanks for the help.